# Visual Basic Web API on IIS Returns 404 Error

Tags: vb.net, iis, iis-8

I have a .NET Visual Basic Web Application that is hosted on IIS 8 that needs to return an API call to url path such as *localhost/test*.

I have an ApiController class defined:

```
<RoutePrefix("test")>
Public Class TestController Inherits ApiController

<Route("")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetMessage As String
  Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

And I believe I have the mapping configured correctly

```
Public Class WebApiConfig
  Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal Config as HttpConfiguration)
    Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
  End Sub
```

In the Global.asax

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
End Sub
```

So here is the strange part, if I run it locally on my Visual Studio, the url path works. However, if I deploy it to the IIS, it returns a 404 Error. Anyone else have this problem?

---

UPDATE:
As requested, I enabled error details and this is the result:
[image: Error Details]

---

UPDATE 2:
[image: Handler Mapping]

---

Here is the install for ASP.NET on IIS
[image: IIS Install]

Comment: Please enable IIS detailed error message and post a screenshot. It is important to know which handler report this 404 error.  If the 404 error is reported by static file handler, please ensure IIS asp.net feature has been enabled in server manager add role and feature.

Comment: @JokiesDing I followed your instructions and it seems like you were right. However, I do believe the ASP.NET feature is enabled. When I go Server Manager and add features, I see ASP.NET 3.5 & ASP.NET 4.5 is installed, unless that isn't what you were referring to.

Comment: Please check your IIS handlers. Did you see ExtensionlessUrlhandler there? It sounds like asp.net handler is not imported correctly.

Comment: @JokiesDing So I checked the Handler Mapping (see image) and there is an ExtensionlessUrlHandler present. It is the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_XXbit.

Comment: @JokiesDing So the reason why I don't think this is working is because my application is in classic mode. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure IIS NET Extensibility 4.5 has also been installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

It seems that **ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0** is missing on your side.
[image]

If this handler is missing, IIS return 404 all the time.

Comment: I followed the steps to the document you provided, but I think it is already installed (see image above).

Comment: Did you see the integrated handler in your handlers list? If it is not listed, could you get it work by register <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" /> in applicationhost.config handlers section?

Comment: So I checked the application host and that line is there. However one thing I noticed is the precondition. My web application is running in classic mode:

<add name="TestApp" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic">
             ...
</add>

Does this mean, I cannot run the missing handler on my web app. would adding classicMode to the precondition fix that?